# Error while exporting customer csv in magento 1.9.3

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to export customer csv from magento admin customer page but it is always giving me network error and same issue from System>Import/Export>Dataflow-profiles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check you memory_limit, it should not be less then 512M. Also you can check the error by enabling log (Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes) and then check these files )

1) var/log/system.log
2) var/log/exception.log

Comment: memory_limit is good but it is giving me exception error 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Ve_Forum_Block_Navigation' in /chroot/home/pompusao/pompusa.org/html/app/Mage.php:595

Comment: Can you please disable this extension and see if it is working?